# Redis Spring write to master , read from slave , no sentinel

Tags: spring, spring-data-redis

I want have a setup of redis where I write to master and read from slave, without any sentinel.

I can see spring does have an article for above here :

https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/redis/docs/2.2.0.M1/reference/html/#redis:write-to-master-read-from-replica

I am using `@Cacheable` annotation for caching, where do I specify that read should happen from master and write from slave?

Answer (score 0):

The write-to-master/read-from-slave is implemented in the lettuce redis client.  It is transparent to your application code